# Ganache QuickStart displaying only 0.0.0.0 - All Interfaces on Windows10

Tags: ganache

I restarted Ganache several times
Uninstall and reinstall the Program still getting the same error.

[image: Screenshot of Error]

Comment: DId you try restarting windows? What's the problem using 0.0.0.0?

Comment: Yes. I restarted my Window severally. And the interface 0.0.0.0 does not show the blockchain accounts page where you can access the blocks, transactions, and contracts.

Comment: Check wikipedia for the exact meaning https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/0.0.0.0. In this case it is used as a wildcard, ganache should listen in the server local ip addresses. So you could access through 127.0.0.1 and the local lan ip if you were connected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know if this helps someone that might have this same issue in the future.
But after two weeks of research and retrying everything I possibly can.
What I did to fix this issue was to:
1.) Delete my node.js app, also the File from C:\ Program Files

2.) Deleted Ganache file from C:\User\owner>\AppData\Roaming

3.) And reinstall Ganache app.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: woah, that is a lot of pain. :-(

Comment: That does help, thank you.  This just worked for me when I had the same issue on Ganache 2.5.4.  I only had to perform step 2, deleting the Ganache data from C:\Users\\[Me]\AppData\Roaming\Ganache.

Comment: @zombat Glad it could help

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Zombat that option work by only deleting the C:\Users[Me]\AppData\Roaming\Ganache. folder and reinstalling the Ganache software.

Answer (score 0):

After reading Harry's answer, I was able to get past this by deleting the Ganache directory in %AppData%.
I didn't have to get rid of node, but I had in the day or so prior changed to the lts version of node and monkeyed about with the nvm for windows.

I don't know if that had anything to do with it or just coincidence, and I did have it running after doing that, but then Windows Update rebooted my machine while I was away from it for a bit and that's when I found I couldn't restart Ganache for windows.