# Truffle migration from within WSL not connecting to Ganache

Tags: truffle, ganache, windows, ubuntu

Truffle migrate and test would not connect to Ganache[image]

[[image][image][image]

Comment: please check if your truffle-config.js have correct details as shown in ganache GUI. 

and try to post those details as well,

Comment: Hello @Muhammad-Faizan I just included a screenshot of my truffle-config.js file with Ganache settings. 
I hope this sheds more light of my issue.

Comment: Have you tried manually changing the network id from the config to 5777? Posting some error logs after running migrate would also help.

Comment: Tried 5777 for the network_id not still working. Also attached the Terminal error screenshot

Answer (score 2):

Hello I hope this helps someone that goes through this same issue.
What i did was to change the IP hostname in ganache to 172.30.16.1 -vEthernet(WSL).

To do this follow these steps

1. Open ganache
2. Go to settings
3. Click on server tab
4. Select XXX.XX.XX.X - vEthernet(WSL) from `HOSTNAME` dropdown, your ip address might be different from mine mentioned above

and then match it on the host variable in the truffle-config.js file. And it worked.

Comment: 2 days ago i was trying to help, in comments, today i faced same issue and came here to look for solution lol, how tables turn. 

sorry i wasn't aware you were on wsl. now i know :-p

Comment: Yeah, it's cool. Also if you begin to experience a problem with your Ganache server only showing "0.0.0.0 - All Interfaces", you can see a solution **[here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/117779/ganache-quickstart-displaying-only-0-0-0-0-all-interfaces-on-windows10/118159#118159)**

Comment: hahaha, man i actually fell into the problem, couldn't solve it moved to ganache-cli on wsl, as that is less painful to configure.

Comment: ganache gui will work with the All Interfaces 0.0.0.0 setting but you have to a real address for wsl network/nat for host in truffle-config.js.  
it doesn't help that network range can change after each reboot. annoying